# How do I reverse a loop halfway through?

Tags: css, loops, for-loop, iteration, stylus

I have this code:

```
for i in (1..5) 
 div:nth-child({i})::after
  content \'i*i\'

for i in (6..10) 
 div:nth-child({i})::after
  ij = (i - 5)
  content \'(ij*ij)\'

for i in (1..10) 
  div:nth-child({i})
  ij = (i - 5)
  if i >= 6
   height ij * ij px
  else 
   height i * i px
```

Which outputs this:

[image]

But I need it to reverse at 25, so it goes:

1 4 9 16 25 25 16 9 4 1

Not sure how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you calculate ij , from ***ij = (i - 5)*** to ***ij = 11 - i***

```
for i in (1..5) 
 div:nth-child({i})::after
  content \'i*i\'

for i in (6..10) 
 div:nth-child({i})::after
  ij = 11-i
  content \'(ij*ij)\'

for i in (1..10) 
  div:nth-child({i})
  ij = 11-i
  if i >= 6
   height ij * ij px
  else 
   height i * i px
```

Comment: How did I miss that!?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

ok , i will give you a way to reverse a loop but you need to integrat it in your code by your self
:

```
    var irt=1;
    for(i=0;(i<10 && irt>0) || (i>0 && irt<0) ;i+=irt){
    if(i==5){//this is where it well bi reversed
    irt=-1;
    }
//do whatever you want to do here
    }
```